# Are there any consequences to having a negative balance on a credit card?

Tags: canada, credit-card, credit-score, balance

I have two credit cards, a VISA and a MasterCard.

I primarily use my MasterCard and only use my VISA when MC isn't accepted. I went about 18 months without using my VISA (I didn't use it at all in 2010. I don't know if there are consequences to that either...). For some odd reason I received a cash back of $1.25 in January, putting my balance at -$1.25.

I finally used my VISA again today, but I had forgotten about the negative balance so it remained on my card all this time.

Is having a negative balance for so long going to hurt me in any way? I'm Canadian if it matters.

Comment: How long exactly have you had a credit?  In the US I had a card that had a small balance and they sent me a check (for less that a dollar) after 90 days.  I think that is the card member agreement, but perhaps it is a law.

Comment: @MrChrister, I've had my VISA account for about 4-5 years now.

Comment: I mean how long have you had a credit on the card.  How long have they owed you $1.25?

Comment: @MrChrister, oh sorry. It was credited to me at the beginning of January. So about 5 months.

Comment: Credit card companies wont report what they owe you to the credit bureaus - so it's probably being seen in the system as a $0 balance with the same nett effect as $0.

Comment: @gef05, if you're sure about that, please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ Brandon. I've spent some time looking, but I can't find an official statement just anecdotal refs, so I'll refrain from posting as answer. Hopefully someone has an official reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What impact does overpaying credit card bill have on credit score?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/what-impact-does-overpaying-credit-card-bill-have-on-credit-score)

Comment: I really liked your way of managing. Do you know what your credit score is?
Or did you apply for any credit line like mortgage etc and did it pass with this management. Yours Thankfully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A credit balance can happen any time you have a store return, but paid the bill in full. It's no big deal. Why not just charge the next gas purchase or small grocery store purchase, to cycle it through?

Yes - unused cards can get canceled by the bank, and that can hurt your credit score. In the US anyway. I'm guessing it's the same system or similar in Canada.

Comment: How does this affect credit utilization, though? Does it count as <0? (The comments above seem inconclusive)

Answer (score 5):

The only consequence I could see is that they have your money until they pay you back.

I'd just do what JoeTaxpayer says and get it back.

Answer (score 2):

I have a visa with Scotiabank and I purposefully keep a negative balance at times. The guy at the bank said it was a great idea. I have never received a cheque, nor do I want one. The reason is that it allows me to make quick purchases without having to worry about paying back and due dates. Only with large purchases do I allow myself to do that. I still check in with my account every once in a while just to make sure everything is all right. It allows for good money management and piece of mind. I have been doing it for a couple of years and have not been penalized at all. (Wouldn't really make sense to do so though.)